# Can the web database contain multiple versions of a single item?

Tags: information-architecture

I know that master database contains all the versions of an item.

Does the web database also contain all the versions of an item?

Or web database can only contain a single version of an item?

Comment: Could you clarify as to whether this is functionality you're looking for, or an issue you're seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.  The master database contains all versions of any given item per language.

In normal senario and before sitecore 8.1, The web database only contains a single version of each item, per language.

But, from sitecore 8.1 onwards, there is a scenario where multiple versions of a single item can exist.
i.e.
when item have an Active Test running for different versions of the same language of that item

https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2015/10/multiple-versions-of-item-in-web.html

Comment: hmm... okay.. is there no other way that web database contain multiple versions of single item ?

Comment: it would appear, that in Sitecore 8.1 at least, we are seeing items in Web with multiple versions. not just language versions, but actual Version versions.

Comment: i think it is when you are using AB testing on same item's versions...

Comment: Updated my answer scFootsteps - I always forget about content testing!